# How to apply MD5withRSA on string in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, rsa, md5

I am new at practical cryptography. 
I am working with 3rd part API server, and I should sign everything (concatenation of string parameters) what I send to API. For this they gave me certificate based on my public key. Now, I should apply `MD5withRSA` on a string and apply `Base64` on result. This will be sign parameter which API server eventually checks. I do not how to do it in Java. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: **MD5**withRSA??? Your assignment is not meant for some serious application, is it?

Comment: The answer would be to use `Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA")`. I don't know what else you expect us to answer. Or, as a friend used to say "I don't hear you typing yet..."

Comment: @mkI yes I have read that MD5withRSA is not very strong

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    private final static String PRIVATE_KEY = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
            "??????????????????????????????????????\n" +
            "??????????????????????????????????????\n" +
            "??????????????????????????????????????\n" +
            "???????????????????????" +
            "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String concatedString = "agent:1af:topup:999756:10.00:08/02/2019 09:57:40";
        StringBuilder pkcs8Lines = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(PRIVATE_KEY));
        String line;
        while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            pkcs8Lines.append(line);
        }
        String pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Lines.toString();
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replaceAll("\\s+","");

        byte [] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pkcs8Pem);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        Signature md5withrsa = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
        md5withrsa.initSign(privKey);

        md5withrsa.update(concatedString.getBytes());
        byte[] res = md5withrsa.sign();
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(res));


    }
}
```